# Displaying information in 3D window text object if ray .positive own.text = (object_one)

Tags: python, game-engine

I have two object in a scene and a text object. I want the reading object to gather information from objects `object_one` and `object_two` on scene and have text object to display info from those objects.

Something like `own.text = (reading_object)`.

I am using a ray sensor to detect `object_one` and `object_tw`o information.I need this information to be displayed as a text object.
Something like

```
object_one = scene.object["object_one"]
object_two = scene.object["object_two"]

Scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

ray = cont.sensors["ray"]

if ray.positive:
    own.text = own.target
    target = str(["text"])
```

Comment: What information you want to show? How should the text object know what object has this information?

Comment: Do you want information from the object detected by the RaySensor?

Comment: @Monster From the user's edit, yes.

Comment: exactly! I am using a ray sensor to detect object_one and object_two information.I need this information to be displayed as a text object. Something like

Comment: I still do not know what information you want to show. What should the text object show when object_one gets detected?

Comment: I need the property name given to object to show up.In this case that would be object_one or object_two.